# Can multiple templates be extended by one template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, multiple-inheritance, extends

Let's say there are `base_a.html`, `base_b.html`, `a.html`, `b.html`, `c.html`.

`a.html` extends `base_a.html` and `b.html` extends `base_b.html`.
And `c.html` has to extend both `base_a.html` and `base_b.html`.

It will be easier to understand this situation if you think `base_a.html` contains reply functionalities and `base_b.html` contains search functionalities.

Can I use multiple inheritance in Django template?
Or do I have to use include instead of extends?

Comment: I think include might be the better fit. If crafted just right, comes in handy if you start using some ajax to update just that section (with search results perhaps). base_b.html could be included in the in base, then that div be updated via ajax call to url which returns the partial with the search functionalities and results. Hope that makes sense. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As stated at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance),

> If you use `{% extends %}` in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template.

That suggests that an `{% extends %}` tag cannot be placed in the second line, that is, you cannot have two `{% extends %}` tags.

Your case can easily be solved with `{% include %}` tags. For example:

In `a.html`:

```
{% include 'base_a.html' %}
```

In `b.html`:

```
{% include 'base_b.html' %}
```

In `c.html`:

```
{% include 'base_a.html' %}
{% include 'base_b.html' %}
```

Of course, `base_a.html` and `base_b.html` should only contain the specific block you want to reuse, not a full HTML template.

Comment: Okay Thanks. It seems it's reasonable to use include.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can extend different or same templates.

For example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%     block content     %}

    <h1>Content goes here</h1>

{% include 'base.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image: multiple template in same page]

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to other answers, one template can extend only one template with [{% extends %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) but not multiple templates.

So, if one template tries to extend multiple templates with `{% extends %}` as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base1.html" %}
{% extends "base2.html" %}
```

Then, the error below occurs:

> 'extends' cannot appear more than once in the same template

Comment: This is a reiteration of what @LostMyGlasses has said in their answer, when they quote from the docs.